# Не работает в Chrome анимация файла svg, добавленного в HTML c помощью < obejct>

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, анимация, dom

смысл: берем `dom` из внешнего `svg` файла и подключаем его в `HTML`

```
<object id="hud" type="image/svg+xml" data="images/hud1.svg"></object>
```

и анимируем

```
var tween1 = document.getElementById('hud').contentDocument.getElementById('tween1'),
tween2 = document.getElementById('hud').contentDocument.getElementById('tween2'),
tween3 = document.getElementById('hud').contentDocument.getElementById('tween3'),
tween4 = document.getElementById('hud').contentDocument.getElementById('tween4'),
tween5 = document.getElementById('hud').contentDocument.getElementById('tween5');
TweenMax.to(tween1 , 200, {rotation:2880, transformOrigin:"50% 50%",repeat:-1});
TweenMax.to(tween2 , 300, {rotation:-720, transformOrigin:"50% 50%",repeat:-1});
TweenMax.to(tween3 , 200, {rotation:1440, transformOrigin:"50% 50%",repeat:-1});
TweenMax.to(tween4 , 400, {rotation:-720, transformOrigin:"50% 50%",repeat:-1});
TweenMax.to(tween5 , 200, {rotation:360, transformOrigin:"50% 50%",repeat:-1});
```

код пока что это весь. будет просто анимированный фон.
svg это кусок с первым объектом. при вставке кода svg в html все работает везде.
думаю проблема в  getю вот только как правильно не знаю.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="hud" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 911.6 911.6" enable-background="new 0 0 911.6 911.6" xml:space="preserve">

<g id="tween1">
 <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="525.6,453 525.6,458.5 543.3,458.5 543.3,453  "/>
 <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" fill-opacity="0" points="525.4,462.7 524.6,468.1 542.1,470.6 542.9,465.2  "/>
 
  <rect x="528.7" y="468.6" transform="matrix(0.275 -0.9614 0.9614 0.275 -73.776 857.1205)" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-opacity="0" width="5.4" height="17.7"/>
 
  <rect x="525" y="478.9" transform="matrix(0.4061 -0.9138 0.9138 0.4061 -132.252 771.9451)" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-opacity="0" width="5.5" height="17.7"/>
 <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" fill-opacity="0" points="516.5,490.4 513.6,495 528.6,504.4 531.5,499.8  "/>
 <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" fill-opacity="0" points="511.1,498.5 507.6,502.6 521.1,514 524.6,509.8  "/>
 <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" fill-opacity="0" points="504.6,505.7 500.6,509.4 512.4,522.5 516.4,518.8  "/>
 <polygon opacity="1.000000e-002" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="497.2,512 492.7,515 502.6,529.7 
  507.1,526.7  "/>
 <polygon opacity="3.000000e-002" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="488.9,517.2 484.1,519.6 491.8,535.5 
  496.7,533.1  "/>
 <polygon opacity="5.000000e-002" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="480.1,521.2 474.9,522.9 480.4,539.7 
  485.5,538  "/>
 <polygon opacity="7.000000e-002" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="470.7,523.9 465.4,524.9 468.4,542.3 
  473.8,541.3  "/>
 
  <rect x="456" y="525.4" transform="matrix(0.9994 -3.593403e-002 3.593403e-002 0.9994 -18.9025 16.8296)" opacity="9.000000e-002" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " width="5.4" height="17.7"/>
 <polygon opacity="0.11" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="451.4,525.4 446,524.8 444.1,542.4 449.5,542.9  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.13" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="441.7,524 436.4,522.7 432.2,539.9 437.4,541.2  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.17" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="432.4,521.4 427.3,519.3 420.7,535.7 425.7,537.8  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.2" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="423.5,517.5 418.7,514.7 409.9,530.1 414.6,532.8  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.23" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="415.2,512.4 410.9,509 400,522.9 404.3,526.3  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.25" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="407.7,506.1 403.9,502.2 391.2,514.5 395,518.4  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.27" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="401.2,498.9 398,494.5 383.7,504.9 386.9,509.3  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.29" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="395.7,490.9 393.1,486.1 377.5,494.4 380.1,499.2  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.31" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="391.4,482.1 389.5,477 372.9,483.1 374.8,488.2  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.34" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="388.3,472.9 387.2,467.6 369.9,471.2 371,476.6  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.37" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="386.6,463.3 386.2,457.9 368.6,459.1 368.9,464.6  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.4" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="386.2,453.6 386.6,448.2 369,446.9 368.6,452.4  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.43" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="387.2,443.9 388.3,438.6 371,434.9 369.9,440.2  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.45" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="389.5,434.5 391.4,429.3 374.8,423.3 372.9,428.4  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.48" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="393.1,425.4 395.7,420.6 380.1,412.3 377.5,417.1  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.5" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="398,417 401.2,412.6 386.9,402.2 383.7,406.6  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.53" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="403.9,409.3 407.7,405.4 395,393.1 391.2,397  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.57" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="410.9,402.5 415.2,399.1 404.3,385.2 400,388.6  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.6" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="418.7,396.7 423.4,394 414.6,378.7 409.9,381.4  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.63" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="427.3,392.1 432.4,390.1 425.7,373.7 420.7,375.7  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.67" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="436.4,388.8 441.7,387.4 437.4,370.3 432.2,371.6  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.7" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="445.9,386.7 451.4,386.1 449.5,368.6 444.1,369.1  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.75" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="455.7,386 461.1,386.2 461.7,368.5 456.3,368.3  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.78" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="465.4,386.6 470.7,387.6 473.8,370.2 468.4,369.2  "/>
 
  <rect x="471.4" y="378.3" transform="matrix(0.3089 -0.9511 0.9511 0.3089 -30.5141 720.0435)" opacity="0.81" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " width="17.7" height="5.4"/>
 <polygon opacity="0.85" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="484.1,391.9 488.9,394.3 496.7,378.4 491.8,376  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.87" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="492.7,396.4 497.2,399.5 507.1,384.8 502.6,381.8  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.91" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="500.6,402.1 504.6,405.8 516.4,392.6 512.4,389  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.94" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="507.6,408.8 511.1,413 524.6,401.7 521.1,397.5  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.97" fill="#FFFFFF" enable-background="new    " points="513.6,416.5 516.5,421.1 531.5,411.8 528.6,407.1  "/>
 <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="518.5,424.9 520.7,429.9 536.9,422.7 534.7,417.7  "/>
 <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="522.2,433.9 523.7,439.1 540.7,434.3 539.2,429  "/>
 <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="524.6,443.4 525.4,448.7 542.9,446.3 542.1,440.9  "/>
 <g>
  <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M404,604.4c-35.7-12.5-67-37.7-86.4-73.4l-46.5,23.9c26,48.5,68.5,82.7,116.9,99.3L404,604.4z"/>
  <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M604.5,507.6c-12.4,35.7-37.7,67.1-73.4,86.4l23.9,46.5c48.5-26,82.7-68.4,99.2-116.9L604.5,507.6z"/>
  <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M307.2,403.9c12.5-35.7,37.7-67,73.4-86.4L356.7,271c-48.5,26-82.7,68.5-99.2,116.9L307.2,403.9z"/>
  <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M507.7,307.1c35.7,12.5,67,37.7,86.4,73.4l46.5-23.9c-26-48.5-68.4-82.7-116.9-99.2L507.7,307.1z"/>
 </g>
 <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M206,705.7c95.8,95.8,235,128.3,363.4,84.9l5-1.7l-6.3-18.7c94.1-33.6,168.7-108.2,202.3-202.3l18.7,6.4
  l1.7-5c43.4-128.4,10.9-267.6-84.9-363.4S470.8,77.6,342.5,121l-5,1.7l6.3,18.7C249.7,175,175.1,249.5,141.6,343.6l-18.6-6.3
  l-1.7,5C77.6,470.7,110.2,609.9,206,705.7z M773.7,557.9c10.3-32.2,16-66.5,16-102.1c0-184.4-149.4-333.8-333.8-333.8
  c-35.6,0-69.9,5.6-102.1,16l-2.9-8.6c123.1-39.6,255.7-7.6,347.4,84c91.6,91.7,123.6,224.3,84,347.4L773.7,557.9z M455.9,775.1
  c-176.4,0-319.4-143-319.4-319.4s143-319.3,319.4-319.3s319.3,142.9,319.3,319.3C775.2,632.1,632.2,775.1,455.9,775.1z
   M129.5,350.7l8.5,2.9c-10.3,32.2-16,66.5-16,102.1c0,184.4,149.5,333.8,333.8,333.8c35.6,0,69.9-5.6,102.1-16l2.9,8.5
  c-123.1,39.6-255.8,7.7-347.4-84C121.8,606.5,89.9,473.9,129.5,350.7z"/>
</g>
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что в хроме не работает?

Comment: @abooks abooks этого кода недостаточно, приведи более полный код анимации и **обязательно** - код svg файла  , так как именно в этом чаще всего кроется причина/ Chrome и FF несколько по разному понимают svg

Comment: фон белый у всех полигонов-разумеется не видно

Comment: не в цвете дело, фон то #000 )))

Comment: @abooks abooks добавлен вариант ответа без JS https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/827854/28748

Answer (score 2):

Причина отказа работы в `chrome` - **при локальном расположении файлов `svg`**, `chrome` не работает. Файлы должны находиться на серверной стороне.
Дам другой вариант решения анимации без `JS`.

Этот вариант отличается в части анимации от предыдущего ответа, тем, как сделана анимация,- не всего содержимого svg файла целиком, а отдельных его частей.

### Pure SVG

Векторные редакторы оставляют много служебной информации. Убрал её, чтобы файл стал легче, я так понял что вы хотите сделать свой, оригинальный лоадер. 
Добавил две анимации вращения самого лоадера по часовой стрелке:

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" dur="4s"  values="0 456 456;360 456 456;" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

и анимацию вращения бордюра против часовой стрелки:

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" dur="120s"  values="360 456 456;0 456 456;" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

Из кода видно, что команды анимации практически идентичны, различия в атрибуте `values="начальный угол X Y;конечный угол X Y"`

Пример отдельного файла с анимацией:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="hud" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="50%" height="50%"
  viewBox="0 0 911.6 911.6">

<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/>
  <g id="tween1" fill="#FFFFFF">
 <polygon  points="525.6,453 525.6,458.5 543.3,458.5 543.3,453  "/>
 <polygon  fill-opacity="0" points="525.4,462.7 524.6,468.1 542.1,470.6 542.9,465.2  "/>
 
  <rect x="528.7" y="468.6" transform="matrix(0.275 -0.9614 0.9614 0.275 -73.776 857.1205)" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-opacity="0" width="5.4" height="17.7"/>
 
  <rect x="525" y="478.9" transform="matrix(0.4061 -0.9138 0.9138 0.4061 -132.252 771.9451)" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-opacity="0" width="5.5" height="17.7"/>
 <polygon  fill-opacity="0" points="516.5,490.4 513.6,495 528.6,504.4 531.5,499.8  "/>
 <polygon  fill-opacity="0" points="511.1,498.5 507.6,502.6 521.1,514 524.6,509.8  "/>
 <polygon  fill-opacity="0" points="504.6,505.7 500.6,509.4 512.4,522.5 516.4,518.8  "/>
 <polygon opacity="1.000000e-002"  points="497.2,512 492.7,515 502.6,529.7 
  507.1,526.7  "/>
 <polygon opacity="3.000000e-002"   points="488.9,517.2 484.1,519.6 491.8,535.5 
  496.7,533.1  "/>
 <polygon opacity="5.000000e-002"   points="480.1,521.2 474.9,522.9 480.4,539.7 
  485.5,538  "/>
 <polygon opacity="7.000000e-002"   points="470.7,523.9 465.4,524.9 468.4,542.3 
  473.8,541.3  "/>
 
  <rect x="456" y="525.4" transform="matrix(0.9994 -3.593403e-002 3.593403e-002 0.9994 -18.9025 16.8296)" opacity="9.000000e-002"   width="5.4" height="17.7"/>
 
 <polygon opacity="0.11"   points="451.4,525.4 446,524.8 444.1,542.4 449.5,542.9  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.13"   points="441.7,524 436.4,522.7 432.2,539.9 437.4,541.2  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.17"   points="432.4,521.4 427.3,519.3 420.7,535.7 425.7,537.8  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.2"    points="423.5,517.5 418.7,514.7 409.9,530.1 414.6,532.8  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.23"  points="415.2,512.4 410.9,509 400,522.9 404.3,526.3  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.25"   points="407.7,506.1 403.9,502.2 391.2,514.5 395,518.4  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.27"   points="401.2,498.9 398,494.5 383.7,504.9 386.9,509.3  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.29"   points="395.7,490.9 393.1,486.1 377.5,494.4 380.1,499.2  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.31"   points="391.4,482.1 389.5,477 372.9,483.1 374.8,488.2  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.34"   points="388.3,472.9 387.2,467.6 369.9,471.2 371,476.6  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.37"   points="386.6,463.3 386.2,457.9 368.6,459.1 368.9,464.6  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.4"   points="386.2,453.6 386.6,448.2 369,446.9 368.6,452.4  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.43"   points="387.2,443.9 388.3,438.6 371,434.9 369.9,440.2  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.45"   points="389.5,434.5 391.4,429.3 374.8,423.3 372.9,428.4  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.48"   points="393.1,425.4 395.7,420.6 380.1,412.3 377.5,417.1  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.5"   points="398,417 401.2,412.6 386.9,402.2 383.7,406.6  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.53"   points="403.9,409.3 407.7,405.4 395,393.1 391.2,397  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.57"   points="410.9,402.5 415.2,399.1 404.3,385.2 400,388.6  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.6"   points="418.7,396.7 423.4,394 414.6,378.7 409.9,381.4  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.63"   points="427.3,392.1 432.4,390.1 425.7,373.7 420.7,375.7  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.67"   points="436.4,388.8 441.7,387.4 437.4,370.3 432.2,371.6  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.7"   points="445.9,386.7 451.4,386.1 449.5,368.6 444.1,369.1  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.75"   points="455.7,386 461.1,386.2 461.7,368.5 456.3,368.3  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.78"   points="465.4,386.6 470.7,387.6 473.8,370.2 468.4,369.2  "/>
 
  <rect x="471.4" y="378.3" transform="matrix(0.3089 -0.9511 0.9511 0.3089 -30.5141 720.0435)" opacity="0.81"  width="17.7" height="5.4"/>
 <polygon opacity="0.85"   points="484.1,391.9 488.9,394.3 496.7,378.4 491.8,376  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.87"   points="492.7,396.4 497.2,399.5 507.1,384.8 502.6,381.8  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.91"   points="500.6,402.1 504.6,405.8 516.4,392.6 512.4,389  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.94"   points="507.6,408.8 511.1,413 524.6,401.7 521.1,397.5  "/>
 <polygon opacity="0.97"   points="513.6,416.5 516.5,421.1 531.5,411.8 528.6,407.1  "/>
 <polygon  points="518.5,424.9 520.7,429.9 536.9,422.7 534.7,417.7  "/>
 <polygon  points="522.2,433.9 523.7,439.1 540.7,434.3 539.2,429  "/>
 <polygon  points="524.6,443.4 525.4,448.7 542.9,446.3 542.1,440.9  "/>
   <!-- Add animation border --> 
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" dur="4s"  values="0 456 456;360 456 456;" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </g>  <!-- end tween1 -->
 
 <path  fill="#fff" d="M206,705.7c95.8,95.8,235,128.3,363.4,84.9l5-1.7l-6.3-18.7c94.1-33.6,168.7-108.2,202.3-202.3l18.7,6.4
  l1.7-5c43.4-128.4,10.9-267.6-84.9-363.4S470.8,77.6,342.5,121l-5,1.7l6.3,18.7C249.7,175,175.1,249.5,141.6,343.6l-18.6-6.3
  l-1.7,5C77.6,470.7,110.2,609.9,206,705.7z M773.7,557.9c10.3-32.2,16-66.5,16-102.1c0-184.4-149.4-333.8-333.8-333.8
  c-35.6,0-69.9,5.6-102.1,16l-2.9-8.6c123.1-39.6,255.7-7.6,347.4,84c91.6,91.7,123.6,224.3,84,347.4L773.7,557.9z M455.9,775.1
  c-176.4,0-319.4-143-319.4-319.4s143-319.3,319.4-319.3s319.3,142.9,319.3,319.3C775.2,632.1,632.2,775.1,455.9,775.1z
   M129.5,350.7l8.5,2.9c-10.3,32.2-16,66.5-16,102.1c0,184.4,149.5,333.8,333.8,333.8c35.6,0,69.9-5.6,102.1-16l2.9,8.5
  c-123.1,39.6-255.8,7.7-347.4-84C121.8,606.5,89.9,473.9,129.5,350.7z"/>

<g id="dash" fill="#fff"  stroke="none">
  <path  d="M404,604.4c-35.7-12.5-67-37.7-86.4-73.4l-46.5,23.9c26,48.5,68.5,82.7,116.9,99.3L404,604.4z"/>
  <path  d="M604.5,507.6c-12.4,35.7-37.7,67.1-73.4,86.4l23.9,46.5c48.5-26,82.7-68.4,99.2-116.9L604.5,507.6z"/>
  <path  d="M307.2,403.9c12.5-35.7,37.7-67,73.4-86.4L356.7,271c-48.5,26-82.7,68.5-99.2,116.9L307.2,403.9z"/>
  <path  d="M507.7,307.1c35.7,12.5,67,37.7,86.4,73.4l46.5-23.9c-26-48.5-68.4-82.7-116.9-99.2L507.7,307.1z"/>
    <!-- Add animation loader -->  
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" dur="120s"  values="360 456 456;0 456 456;" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </g>
  
</svg>
```

Добавление этого файла svg с сервера в HTML:

```html
<object id="hud" type="image/svg+xml" data="https://svg-art.ru/files/images/hud1.svg"></object>
```

Comment: Как всегда....)))

Answer (score 1):

помогло

```js
window.onload = function() {

var hud = document.getElementById("hud"),
svgDoc = hud.getSVGDocument(),
tween1 = svgDoc.getElementById('tween1');

TweenMax.to(tween1 , 200, {rotation:2880, transformOrigin:"50% 50%",repeat:-1});

};
```

оказывется у хрома есть запрет на загрузку по getSVGDocument() локальных файлов.
поставил код на сервак  - все заработало.